# Как лучше передать папку продакшн клиенту?

Tags: git, github, веб-программирование, webstorm, build

Возник такой вопрос: на локальном компьютере работал над проектом (в webstorm), в работе использовал gulp и соответственно версия сайта на продакшн находится в папке build, с которой я деплою файлы на собственный тестовый сайт (клиенту так удобнее смотреть), кроме того я коммитил проект на git. Вопрос теперь такой, как правильно передать клиенту файлы с папки build?

Comment: Что за хост? Какой сервер?

Comment: у меня? да бесплатный хостинг (hostinger), но это при чем тут? я спрашиваю как правильно передать клиенту файлы или на хостинг его залить напрямую или с репозитория git отправить.

Comment: http://bitte.net.ua/blog/kak-zalit-sayt-na-hosting/ Вот как залить на хостинг через фтп.

Comment: Вы меня совсем не поняли, зачем мне фтп если я работаю с webstorm, кроме того я файлы залил на хостинг тестовый (смотрите выше). Вопрос ка кправильно передать папку продакшн клиенту?

Comment: Собрать проект, запаковать в архив и передать клиенту. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: иными словами если я вас правильно понял: gulp компилит в папку build, сборка готова, ее архивирую и отправляю клиенту.

Comment: @zorro, можете и просто деплоить измененные файлы прямо из gulp'а на сервер клиента через SFTP/WebDav, например, либо сразу архивировать и отправлять билд на почту клиента. Отдельной независимой задачей, либо после успешного билда и тестов(получится вполне себе Continuous Delivery)

Comment: спасибо за дельные советы